Execute reusable workflows in parallel and do status reporting on completion
Requirements:

execute a deployment per tenant
await the result for each tenant
collect the deployment status of each job to send notification to other systems.

My understanding is, fail-fast: false will allow the deployment matrix to complete regardless of errors.
I am struggling to get the success / error status  of the reusable jobs to work on the logging.
#workflow that initiates deployment
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [closed]
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  deploy:
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        tenant: ["tenant1", "tenant2"]
    uses: ./.github/workflows/reusable-workflow.yml

    with:
      aws_env: 'staging'
      tenant: ${{ matrix.tenant }}
    secrets: inherit

  post_deploy:
    needs: deploy
    steps: #... do something with result of deploy


# reusable-workflow.yml
# this job is called in another github action using a matrix strategy per tenant
on:
  workflow_call:
     inputs:
      tenant:
        description: 'tenant'
        type: string
        default: 'test'
      aws_env:
        description: 'AWS ENV'
        type: string
        default: 'staging'

jobs:
  deploy_1:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/docker.yml
    name: Deploy api
    with:
      aws_env: ${{ inputs.aws_env }}
      module: "api"
      tenant: ${{ inputs.tenant }}

  deploy_2:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/docker.yml
    name: Deploy other_service
    with:
      aws_env: ${{ inputs.aws_env }}
      module: "other_service"
      tenant: ${{ inputs.tenant }}


You could save the reusable workflow conclusion status in an artifact for each matrix run (using the tenant input in the artifact name, that way it will be unique), and then add a job in your main workflow getting all artifacts and checking those statuses before performing the operation you need for logging.

Those threads 1 and 2 might help with how to achieve what I explained
